# JS button to Call WebService / Apex, and return id

Tags: apex, javascript, custom-button

I have created a JS button, which calls a class, and clones a record with it's children. I am struggling to pass the ID of the newly cloned record back to the button, to then re-direct to the new record. My class is VOID, is this an issue when returning data?

Thanks

JS:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/30.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/30.0/apex.js")}


var CId = "{!Course__c.Id}";

var warning = confirm("Are you sure you want to clone this Course and its related Assessments?");


if (warning == true) { 
sforce.apex.execute("CloneCourse","cloneC",{CId:CId});
alert("Course has been created.");

window.location.href = "/" +cCopy.id;
}
```

APEX:

```
global class CloneCourse{

    webservice static void cloneC(Id CId){

        Course__c c = [SELECT ID,Name,Delivery_Mode__c FROM Course__c WHERE Id = : CId];
        Course__c cCopy = c.clone(false,true);
        cCopy.Name = c.Name +' - clone';
        insert cCopy;

        List<Assessment__c> assessments = new List<Assessment__c>();
        for(Assessment__c a : [SELECT a.Id,a.Title__c,a.Max_Grade__c,a.Course__r.id,a.Assesment_Type__c,a.Assessment_Assessable__c,
            a.Assessment_CaseSafeId__c,a.Grade_Category__c,a.Moodle_ID__c,a.Weighting__c FROM Assessment__c a WHERE Course__c = : c.Id]){
                Assessment__c aCopy = a.clone(false,true);
                aCopy.Course__c = cCopy.Id;
                assessments.add(aCopy);
        }
        insert assessments;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

sforce.apex.execute is an async method and therefore you will need to use callback function. https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008x3bIAA

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/30.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/30.0/apex.js")}


var CId = "{!Course__c.Id}";

var warning = confirm("Are you sure you want to clone this Course and its related Assessments?");
var callback = { 
onSuccess: function(e){
    window.location.href = "/" + e;
}, onFailure: function(error){} };


if (warning == true) { 
sforce.apex.execute("CloneCourse","cloneC",{CId:CId}, callback);
alert("Course has been created.");


}
```

In Your APEX code return the object:

```
global class CloneCourse{

    webservice static string cloneC(Id CId){

        Course__c c = [SELECT ID,Name,Delivery_Mode__c FROM Course__c WHERE Id = : CId];
        Course__c cCopy = c.clone(false,true);
        cCopy.Name = c.Name +' - clone';
        insert cCopy;

        List<Assessment__c> assessments = new List<Assessment__c>();
        for(Assessment__c a : [SELECT a.Id,a.Title__c,a.Max_Grade__c,a.Course__r.id,a.Assesment_Type__c,a.Assessment_Assessable__c,
            a.Assessment_CaseSafeId__c,a.Grade_Category__c,a.Moodle_ID__c,a.Weighting__c FROM Assessment__c a WHERE Course__c = : c.Id]){
                Assessment__c aCopy = a.clone(false,true);
                aCopy.Course__c = cCopy.Id;
                assessments.add(aCopy);
        }
        insert assessments;
        string resultId = Id.valueOf(cCopy.Id);
        return resultId;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for your response. I had tried something similar to this, and received an error - "Void method must not return a value"

Comment: @TheMikeyBoosh ah, try string resultId = Id.valueOf(cCopy.Id) and change webservice static void cloneC to webservice static string cloneC as well

Comment: @ChrisChen You may want to [edit] your answer so it matches the comments.